# Unable to access pass from passbook

Tags: ios, swift, passkit

I have integrated passbook in my iOS app. I have downloaded some passes from Apple site and changed the passTypeIdentifier to my identifier. I am able to add passes to my passbook using following code:

```
let data:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile:path)!
        var error1:NSError?

        let pass = PKPass.init(data: data, error: &error1)
        if(passLib.containsPass(pass)){
            let passArray = passLib.passes()
            sharedUtility.sharedInstance.showAlertUIViewController("Pass Exists", message: String(passArray.count) + "The pass you are trying to add to Passbook is already present.", buttonTitle: "OK", controller: self)
        }
        else{
            let vc:PKAddPassesViewController = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: pass) as PKAddPassesViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

I am able to add passes using above code and also get error that pass already exists in passbook when trying to add same pass again. But I am not able to access the passes added by me. I am using following code to access it:

```
let passArray = passLib.passes()
    if(passArray.count>0){
        let onePass:PKPass = passArray[0]
        print(onePass)
        sharedUtility.sharedInstance.showAlertUIViewController("Pass Found", message: String(passArray.count) + " Found", buttonTitle: "OK", controller: self)
    }
    else{
        sharedUtility.sharedInstance.showAlertUIViewController("Pass Not Found", message: String(passArray.count) + " Found", buttonTitle: "OK", controller: self)
    }
```

I am not able to get any pass in above array. It is always empty. Can anyone suggest me what I am missing here.

Thanks